# Sort array of dicts in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

i am working on Angular7 and Typescript,
i want to sort array of dict in typescript.
here is my data :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Azad University",
      "tedad": 80
    },
    {
      "name": "University of Science and Technology",
      "tedad": 14
    },
    {
      "name": "University of Kurdistan",
      "tedad": 30
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to sort this data by  `tedad` key. how can i do this?
i see this code on stackoverflow but i dont know how to change it that works:

```
items.sort(function(first, second) {
  return second[1] - first[1];
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects based on property in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49048955/sort-array-of-objects-based-on-property-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

In ts file:

```
    sample = {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Azad University",
                "tedad": 80
            },
            {
                "name": "University of Science and Technology",
                "tedad": 14
            },
            {
                "name": "University of Kurdistan",
                "tedad": 30
            }
        ]
    }
constructor(){
    this.sample.data.sort(function(first, second) {
                return (first.tedad - second.tedad);
            });
            console.log(this.sample);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

parameters in `Array.prototype.sort()` are elements of the array. You can access by property of theirs.

```js
const items = {
  "data": [{
      "name": "Azad University",
      "tedad": 80
    },
    {
      "name": "University of Science and Technology",
      "tedad": 14
    },
    {
      "name": "University of Kurdistan",
      "tedad": 30
    }
  ]
}

const sorted = items.data.sort((prev, curr) => prev.tedad - curr.tedad);

console.log(sorted)
```